# Mono GAC DLL Not Found

Tags: c#, linux, dll, mono

I'm very new to mono c# development and I'm having trouble including an external DLL into my application.

I'm using CentOS 7, trying to include the Npgsql.dll module.

My application is bare at the moment as follows

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Npgsql;

public class TestApp {
   static public void Main(string[] la_args) {
      Console.WriteLine("Nothing");
   }
}
```

I included the Npgsql.dll into the GAC

```
# gacutil -i Ngsql.dll
# Installed Npgsql.dll into the gac (/usr/local/lib/mono/gac)
```

But when I try to compile it still produces an error

```
# mcs TestApp.cs
# error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Npgsql' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary answer because I think this might only be a work-around. It seems to compile correctly if I include the dll directly in the compile

```
# mcs TestApp.cs -r:Npgsql.dll
```